# Guid.ToString() in Linq query?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a method which attempts to pull a record from my db with a simple where clause. I have an issue because I'm passing in a string value and matching it to a Guid (uniqueIdentifier). I need the passed value as a string to bind in a DataGrid and I need the method to return a string.

Obviously at run time, LinQ can't compile the query. The `.ToString()` method cannot be compiled into SQL. Any ideas?

```
private string getFileLocation(string LinkGuid)
{
    try
    {
        ISESEntities context = new ISESEntities();

        string query = (from f in context.tbFileAttachments
                where f.CCCPGUID.ToString() == LinkGuid
                select f.FileLocation).First();

        return query;           
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       blah blah
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Switch your logic around and convert the `LinkGuid` paramter to a Guid:

```
private string getFileLocation(string LinkGuid)
{
    try
    {
        Guid search = Guid.Parse(LinkGuid);

        ISESEntities context = new ISESEntities();

        string query = (from f in context.tbFileAttachments
                where f.CCCPGUID == search
                select f.FileLocation).First();

        return query;           
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       blah blah
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks guys. Guid.Parse() method, very useful :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of calling `ToString` on `Guid` field, Convert your parameter string to Guid and then pass that in your query:

```
Guid parameterGuid = Guid.Parse(LinkGuid);
string query = (from f in context.tbFileAttachments
               where f.CCCPGUID == parameterGuid 
               select f.FileLocation).First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, the LINQ provider does not know how to convert `ToString` from a `Guid` property into SQL Query. I would use the `Guid` object to compare, for sample:

```
Entities context = new ISESEntities();

Guid linkGuid = Guid.Parse(LinkGuid);

string query = (from f in context.tbFileAttachments
                where f.CCCPGUID == linkGuid
                select f.FileLocation).First();

return query;
```